# Proving if function is one to one?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $f : (\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}) \to \mathbb{N}$ be defined as:
\begin{equation}
    f(x, y) = \frac{(x + y)(x + y + 1)}{2} + y
\end{equation}
I know that $f(x,y) = f(x',y')$ in order to be a one to one.
So it'll be :
\begin{equation}
\frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2}+ y = \frac{(x'+y')(x'+y'+1)}{2}+ y'
\end{equation}
but I don't know how to prove this exactly, the fraction is throwing me off.

Comment: Note that exactly one of $x+y$ and $x+y+1$ is a multiple of $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We begin by noting that the sets $P_i = \{ x| \frac{i(i-1)}{2} < x \le \frac{i(i+1)}{2} \}$ are disjoint.

Now note that $\frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2}+y$ is in the set $P_{x+y+1}$.

Similarly, we note that $\frac{(x'+y')(x'+y'+1)}{2}+y'$ is in the set $P_{x'+y'+1}$.

Therefore, we must have $x+y=x'+y'$. It follows that $x=x'$, $y=y'$.